# Rounding output value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How can I round my integer result when I apply my function?

am applying the function using,

```
df['value'] = df.apply(function_calc, axis=1)
```

Result for example in new column are **28.1,22.1**

How can I use round function while I apply this function?
Thanks!

Comment: `df['value'] = df.apply(function_calc, axis=1).astype(int)`

Comment: or in function_calc itself, return `int(something)` instead of `something`

Answer (score 1):

See:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.round_.html

```
import numpy as np    
df['value'] = np.round(df.apply(function_calc, axis=1), decimals=0)
```

Using round inside function_calc will likely be significantly slower, as the np.round() is vectorized.